# How to change the start date in Android/Linux?

Tags: android, linux, date, linux-kernel

I am programming an Android system running on an i.MX6 SoM.

For some reasons, I need the Android system to start counting from 2000/01/01 00:00 on first boot. Currently, the Linux kernel under Android set the default start date to be the Epoch (1970/01/01).

How can I change the default start date?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  All linux OSes work with a start date of the epoch, changing it would break a lot of stuff everywhere, if it was even possible (it isn't).  If you need to count relative to some other date, figure out the epoch time of that date and subtract it from the epoch time.  Make a utility function to do that.

Comment: I am afraid my question was not clear enough. I don't have to change the Epoch date necessarily. I just want Android to load a new date on first boot, it is like running a `date` command on boot and setting the system date to be something after year 2000.